# How to override default_scope in client_side_validations gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, client-side-validation, default-scope

I have `default_scope` on most of my models that scopes by `current_user.company`. I'm using the client_side_validations gem on my sign up page which means there is no tenant set.

When the uniqueness validator runs on `@user.email` the default_scope prevents the validation from running properly (because `company_id` is nil) and therefore always looks like a unique result.

My user model:

```
# user.rb
...
default_scope { where(company_id: Company.current_id) }
...
```

This query is run when validating email:

```
Started GET "/validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=true& \
user%5Bemail%5D=me%2B40%40example.com&_=1423897339854" \
for 76.175.168.2 at 2015-02-14 07:02:30 +0000                        
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE \
  "users"."company_id" IS NULL AND "users"."email" = 'me@example.com' LIMIT 1
```

When I remove the `default_scope` from my user model I get the correct result and proper validation:

```
Started GET "/validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=true& \
user%5Bemail%5D=me%2B40%40example.com&_=1423897339854" \
for 76.175.168.2 at 2015-02-14 07:02:30 +0000
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE \
  "users"."email" = 'me@example.com' LIMIT 1
```

What's the most practical way for me to override the `default_scope` when this gem runs the email validator?

Answer (score 1):

Generally i would say: don't use default_scope cause you will run to all sorts of problems like this. Default scope is okay for ordering in my opinion.

But here you can solve it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.default_scope
    #i don't know what company represents here
    where(company_id: Company.current_id) if Company.present?
 end
end
```

You can define default scope as class method like you see above.

See doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: Thanks for your input but this question is more about the client_side_validations gem than the pros and cons of default_scope. I ended up money patching the gem in my app to provide the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think override the default_scope is a good idea.

You should move the logic to controller. I don't know if you are using pundit. It will provider a scope function.

If not, try to move this scope to controller.

```
def current_users
   @users||= User.where(company_id: Company.current_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this question is more about the client_side_validations gem than the pros and cons of default_scope. I ended up money patching the gem in my app to provide the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up money patching the gem within my app to fix my issue. I'll also submit the change to the gem author since I'm not sure if this is a bug or their original desired behaviour.

```
# lib/client_side_validations/active_record/middleware.rb

def self.is_unique?(klass, attribute, value, params)
  ...
  !klass.where(relation).exists?
end

# patched the above line to: !klass.unscoped.where(relation).exists?
```